# Simple code to generate a wordlist of specific type

Tags: python

I need to generate a word list which as first 3 of alphabets 4th a number and 5th again an alphabet . This is the patter . I need to get all possible list of that pattern.

Example aaa0a aaa0b .... to zzz9z

My try was

```
import string
from random import *
password =''.join(choice(string.lowercase) for x in range(3))
password +=choice(string.digits)
password +=choice(string.lowercase)
print password
```

I know its the worst code. Still I made a try myself.

And I wanted to print the output in a text file, how to do that?

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from string import ascii_lowercase, digits
from itertools import product, combinations_with_replacement as cr, chain

for p in product(cr(ascii_lowercase,3), digits,ascii_lowercase):
    print("".join(chain.from_iterable(p)))
```

To write it to a file:

```
with open("foo.txt", "w") as f:
    f.writelines("".join(chain.from_iterable(p)) + "\n"
                 for p in product(cr(ascii_lowercase, 3), digits, ascii_lowercase))
```

Which should give you `851761` unique lines ;)

Comment: I'm sure you could turn this into a comprehension or something :)

Comment: Works great . Can you tell me how to make that save in a text file . Am very thankful to you

Comment: @Shashank, just replace the print with a file.write making sure to add a newline

Comment: @MattDMo, a genexp  will have to do ;)

Comment: I suppose. Still, you violated PEP-8 with your line lengths. **-1!**

Comment: @MattDMo, according to pycharm I was good but a quick import as should definitely satisfy any pep-8 checker!

Comment: an extra space after \n was creating a bit of problem . But finally it worked. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Shashank, that was just a test  I swear ;)

Comment: Nice job, I'm happy now.